# Is it sin to leave Parents after marriage?

Tags: halal-haram

I want to know whether is it sin to leave parents alone in their old age? I am married and i have two kids now i am thinking to go to other country for my children future, i want to know whether is it sin or not.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model I strongly suggest you to take the [tour] and check our [help]. As to your inquiry I think it is necessary to know: Are you their only son (child)?

Comment: This requires elaboration. Are you leaving with their consent? Or are they telling you to not leave? Is there someone to take care of them? Your parents have rights over you and you need to ensure that they will not be violated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a sin, but reccomended to do whatever you can to make sure your parents are taken care of and have everything they need. Also important to visit frequently and love them as best you can. Depends where you are going and how far it is ofcourse.